# Cannot install SQLServer module in Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlps

I try to install Powershell SQLSERVER module by executing the following command as admin (win10, 64Bit) but it fails

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Module -Name SqlServer
PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search 
criteria and module name 'SqlServer'.
Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
At C:\Program 
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1809 
char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: 
(Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 

NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.
InstallPackage
```

I have searched the web, I tried some solutions, I even talked to company admins but without luck. As they told me there is no proxy in the company, only firewall. Other colleagues can run the command without problems. The next command also fails

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PSrepository
WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.
```

Any idea?

Comment: `Get-PSRepository -Verbose`. Also, try `PowerShell -NoProfile` to see if you've got something in your profile that's interfering. If all else fails, you can always try to `Register-PSRepository` manually (`Register-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted -SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/" -Verbose`).

Comment: thanks, I tried everything but fail. When I tried to register PSRepository, it brought back an error saying PowerShell Gallery is currently anavailable

Comment: Then it sounds like you're proxied/firewalled. Try accessing https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2 in your browser; if that fails you know it's not PowerShell's fault. (If that works, it can still be a firewall/anti-virus issue where PowerShell specifically has been blocked from making outgoing connections, or at least not permitted to do so.)

Comment: I can open in my browser both www.powershellgallery.com and https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2. Other colleagues can run all commands thus this happens only on my laptop. The -Verbose command you gave me was useful. Something is wrong with Registered repositories.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into this. I had to run the following:

```
Register-PSRepository -Default
Register-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted -SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/" -Verbose
```

This errored out. Then I was able to run

```
Install-Module sqlserver
```

Comment: Although I got some errors, it finally worked. thanks.

Comment: For me I had to use "Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber" and it worked, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 7):

Mine got fixed enabling tls 1.2

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Answer (score 0):

Too elaborate on @Daniel_Carlozzi answer, in an elevated PowerShell window, I ran `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` which produced no output and then `Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber` which warned about a Untrusted Repository.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing:
Install-Module -Name SqlServer

I tried:
Install-Module SqlServer

I don't know why but it worked.